# Is JDK 8 really important for Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I recently installed Android Studio 2.3.3 on my Mac, but I forgot to install JDK 8 before setting up Android Studio. I am already halfway through the development process of my App, so know I don't want to uninstall Android Studio, then install JDK 8 and again reinstall Android Studio, so should I uninstall Android Studio for JDK 8, is it really that important?

Comment: You're already half way through development, so why would you change if it works?

Comment: You don't need to reinstall ANdroid Studio to get Java 8. Though you may want to get AS 3 beta 2 to avoid jack options, it's a pain to use

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Just a precaution!

Comment: So what should I take as an answer should I install JDK 8 on my other desktops/machines(which I don't want to) before installing Android Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, JDK is important in Android Studio to compile your .java files. As you said you are half way through your development process ,there is a JVM in your machine(not necessarily JDK-8).

Android by default installs a JVM in your computer.
Open a project in Android studio,

Goto `File` -> `Project Structure` -> `SDK location`

There you can see, default `JDK location`, if there is no such thing then,

1.install JDK-8, and Set the Environmental variables.

2.Set the jdk path in the JDK location in the android studio.

Comment: So what should I take as an answer should I install JDK 8 on my other desktops/machines(which I don't want to) before installing Android Studio

Comment: No Android has its own JRE installed in it. You can use it. Or you can download new JDK and use it in android too. It is not necessarily JDK 8, you can use JDK 7 or 6 too based on your project's SDK version.